# How to check if blank cells are present in a excel sheet column using vba

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm transfering excel sheet data into access table. And i'm trying to find whether specified column has any blanks and then prompts the user. How do i check the blank cells in a column using vba.

My Access VBA

```
 Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application
 Dim ExcelBook As New Excel.Workbook        
 Dim rngblankcells As Excel.Range
 StrFileName="C:\temp\sample.xls"

 Set rngblankcells = ExcelBook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("AF1:AF178")
 If Not IsEmpty(rngDefine) Then

  MsgBox "empty"

  Else

  'Tranfer sheet

        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acImport, _
        tablename:=table1, _
        FileName:=StrFileName, Hasfieldnames:=True, _
        Range:="Sheet1!A:BF", SpreadsheetType:=5

  End If
```

But instead of

```
   .Range("AF1:AF178")
```

I need to specify column name. because range is uncertain in all worksheets but having same column names.

Answer (score 0):

If I need to transform data in an Excel spreadsheet as I import it into Access I will go row by row and column by column, perhaps filling a recordset that is connected to an Access database. One thing I might do is check for an empty cell and output a default value if it is empty.

```
IIf(IsEmpty(Cells(rowNumber,colNumber)), "My default value", Cells(rowNumber,colNumber))
```

This answered the initial question, "How to check if blank cells are present in a excel sheet column using vba."

Comment: *rowNumber,colNumber* are not constant. because these numbers may change based on workbook. Is there anyway i can use column name only

Comment: Are you looping through rows?

Comment: no.. i don't see in perticular row, but in overall column

Comment: How is your VBA transferring data from Excel to Access?

Comment: Please try to flesh out your answer a bit more. Just posting a code block without any explanation or context is not good and might not be of much value to people looking for an answer to this question in the future.

Comment: You need to be able to answer this question: How do you know a range's column name before you import it?

Comment: I think that code is self-explanatory, although like with any answer, I had to assume some level of understanding. Perhaps I got that level incorrect.

Comment: what is the *My default value* here

Comment: @vuyy1182 "My default value" is anything you need it to be. Let's say some cells in a column of the spreadsheet have been left empty, but the field must have a value in the database. For your case, it sounds like you want to prompt the user for a value when a cell is empty, so prompt the user for that value and then pass the user supplied value in place of "My default value". You could do this on a cell by cell basis, or you could prompt for the default value of an entire column. When I've done what you are describing here I've known the default value ahead of time and did not need to prompt.